# node-cmd increase maxBuffer size

Tags: node.js

I am using a node package that allows me to get control of the cmd: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

My problem is that I am running into a `stdout maxBuffer exceeded` error. I have found a question that answers this problem:
[Stdout buffer issue using node child_process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429499/stdout-buffer-issue-using-node-child-process)

My problem is, how do I apply this answer to the `node-cmd` package's `cmd.run` or `cmd.get` calls?

Example of a call that is giving the error: (`ng build` runs a BIG Angular command)

```
cmd.get('ng build', (err, data, stderr) => {
    ...
});
```

**I am not sure where to insert something like `{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}`**

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD.

Comment: why do you say that? I am running a command `ng build` in the cmd. It is through a 3rd party thing, but the cmd is still part of the pipeline, and therefore part of the problem.

Comment: Show your CMD batch file or command. There is not one in your question.

Comment: `ng build` is my command. `ng build` is what I would type into cmd

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD. `ng` is a program like `CMD`, it runs itself. And you aren't using full paths, acting like you are typing in `CMD` **BUT** you are not using `CMD` and nor are you typing. I am tired of python and node people tagging their questions CMD. CMD is a Windows tag and neither python or Node are part of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `ng build` command with the `--progress` flat set to false in order to avoid displaying so much output to the console.

`ng build --progress false`

Comment: Wow! What an unexpected answer! Thank you!