# node exec() not firing all data events

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems for big enough stdout output node does not fire `data` events:

Example bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for i in {1..100000}; do
    echo $i
done
```

Running the above script from bash should prints all numbers from 1 to 100k one number per line

However when proxying it via node's `exec`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters

const {exec} = require('child_process');

let stdout = '';

const child = exec('./tmp.sh');

child.stdout.on('data', data => {
    stdout += data;
});

child.stdout.on('close', code => {
    if (code) process.exit(code);
    console.log(stdout.split('\n').slice(0, 3).join('\n'));
    console.log('...');
    console.log(stdout.split('\n').slice(-3).join('\n'));
});
```

For the above script, I'd expect to get:

```
1
2
3
...
99998
99999
100000
```

However when run It returns:

```
1
2
3
...
35984
35985
```

About a third of the output is truncated. Logging inside the `data` handler shows that only 1 data event is fired with 1 chunk

I've tried listening to the `child.on('exit')` event instead with the same result (also `stdout.on('exit')`)

It works the same when replacing `exec` with `spawn`

```
node --version # v5.4.1
osx 10.10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`child_process.exec()` buffers the standard output into a [fixed size buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).  You are likely filling the buffer and thus you don't get the rest of the output.

There is a `maxBuffer` option you can pass to `.exec()` to make the buffer larger or you can use `.spawn()` and receive an unlimited stream of output.

See [Stdout buffer issue using node child_process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429499/stdout-buffer-issue-using-node-child-process) for related info.

Also worth reading: [Difference between spawn and exec of Node.js child_process](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html) and [Stdout of Node.js child_process exec is cut short](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260423/816620).

Comment: i did mention in my post that I tried replacing `spawn` with `exec` and got the same output - for exactly the buffer reasons

Comment: oh nevermind, of course after I go and post on stack overflow and try again one of the things I tried before it ends up working :| goddamit. Thanks!

Comment: @tak3r - Then, please show us the code you used with `.spawn()` because it should be able to receive an unlimited stdout stream.